# HTML5 Date Input Type Interfering with jQuery Datepicker

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI's datepicker for date selections on my site. One of my users just upgraded to the newest version of Chrome, which has built-in native date picker for HTML5. The big problem as the two UIs overlap each other.  The other problem is when the user submits a date, the date in database reverts to "0000-00-00" and is producing bad data.

If I remove the jQuery datepicker, most of the users not using the latest-greatest browsers will not have a popup date picker. And, those who have the newest browser will have two overlapping calendars which breaks the application. My question is how do I disable the newest browsers from displaying the built-in date function and just continue to use the jQuery Datepicker?

Answer (score 39):

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) or similar library to feature detect if the browser supports the `input type=date`, and then load the jQuery UI datepicker if if does not.

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: where do place the code above? Also, do I call the modernizr.js script in my header?

Comment: Yes, you need to reference the moderizr.js in your header with a script tag.  And you would place the above code wherever you are currently calling the `.datepicker()` method.  Posting your existing code would help.

Comment: This solution worked for me! Here are instructions for installing Modernizr: http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing

Comment: Also, if you run into a dependency error with your Modernizr custom build (such as this one - https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/849) do a Google search to see what other selections need to be included in your build. They say this should be fixed in v3.

Answer (score 2):

Either switch from using `input[type=date]` to `input[type=text]` or use Modernizr to detect support for the native datepicker.  I've wrote a post about the implications of both options here - http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you cannot modify form types. For example, I'm using Symfony2 Bundle's FormType.

I had this problem using Genemu jQuery Datepicker, and I solved this problem adding a calendar image button and a litle of css code.

[You can see final result in this link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46575078/datepicker.png)

Here you can read documentation for adding image icon: [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Then, I simple added a css like this (maybe style rules will be different for you):

```
form input[type=date] + img {
    position: relative;
    left: -25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `novalidate` attribute to your form to remove browser's build-in validation.

```
<form action="login.htm" novalidate>
```

See this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp) for more info.