# Can not initialize Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippets of code:

In my JS file:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
    });

$("#performDateView").datepicker({
  minDate: "0",
  maxDate: "+3d",

});

var myDate = new Date(1978,2,11) 

$('#performDateView').datepicker( "setDate", myDate);
```

And in my HTML file:

```
<input type="text" id="performDateView" />
```

Problem:  maxDate and minDate is worked, but setDate property not. I use jQuery 1.9.1  What I should do to solve this problem? Also I have a link: http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/

Comment: You have a syntax error in the minDate/maxDate literal, and your code should likely be wrapped in `$(function() { ... })` since the DOM might not be fully loaded when your datepicker stuff is executing. Also, I think the datepicker extension only supports `input` with `type=text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- The input type should be `text`. You can either have the browser's own datepicker or jQuery UI's datepicker, but not both.
- You've set the datepicker's minimum date to today and maximum date to three days from today. March 1978 doesn't fit into that range so the date isn't set.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/2/

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of input from date to text.

```
<input type="text" id="performDateView" />
```

& if you want to set date then remove minDate

```
minDate: "0",
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think your `type="date"` is messing up with the inbuilt javascript functionality that is provided by jquery UI. You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297827/html5-date-input-type-interfering-with-jquery-datepicker) question on how to resolve it. As far as this bug is concerned, modifying your html to:

```
  <input type="text" id="performDateView" />
```

fixes the default setting for the date. Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RzD5Z/7/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

See jQuery documentation [**here**](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
});
```

This should work as expected; watch closely
 `<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>`

so this

```
$('#performDateView').datepicker( "setDate", new Date(2011,08,04));
```

will work.

Comment: `$("#performDateView").datepicker({ minDate: ...` already initializes it.

Answer (score -2):

change Your below line

```
<input type="date" id="performDateView" />
```

With `<input type="this" id="performDateView" />` this line and

change

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
```

this part with the below

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
```

I also applied it in Your jsFiddle example. It was working there.

Comment: give reason against this negetive vote. otherwise I will ask moderator against this

Comment: marking negative comment does't mean You knows the answer. negative vote is ok but give proper reason in comment.